# Getting vue typeerror cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

I know this type of questions are every where, but I am having problem to find a good answer(I am new to VueJS).I am sorry about that.

I am trying to pass data using vform.

What I am trying to do is adding user details through vform to a table.

Here is my Users.vue code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addNew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNew" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
              <input v-model="form.name" type="text" name="name"
              class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name') }">
              <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

<script>
    export default {
    data(){

        return{

            form: new Form({
                name: ''

            })
        }
    },  
 }
</script>
```

Here is my app.js

```
 require('./bootstrap');

    window.Vue = require('vue');

    import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform';

    window.form = Form;

    Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
    Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)

    import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
    Vue.use(VueRouter)

    let routes = [
      { path: '/dashboard', component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue') },
      { path: '/profile', component: require('./components/Profile.vue') },
      { path: '/users', component: require('./components/Users.vue') }
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
      routes // short for `routes: routes`
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is most likely on the line with this:

```html
<input v-model="form.name" type="text" name="name"
```

You can see it's the only place where `.name` is called. Which means your `form` object is `undefined` and the code is trying to call the attribute `name` on it which throws you an error.

If you look at the [vform README](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform), you will see that the `import` statement is actually inside the component. The issue with your code is that the import inside `app.js` doesn't magically appear inside your component so you cannot do `new Form()` in the Vue component. While you do assign it to the `window` object in `app.js`, you don't re-use it later on and IMO, it's better to import your dependencies explicitly.

So in conclusion, what you need to do is: Add this import statement right after the opening `<script>` tag in your Vue component

```js
import { Form } from 'vform';
```

Comment: Justin Ho Tuan Duong Thank you very much for your time and answer.